# import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor' error

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

I have installed Protractor, typescript, jasmine with type globally and also locally.
Getting following error while running the test via npm install, please guide if anything wrong with the setup.

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\MyFiles\NewTechonologies\Protractor\TypeScript\Test\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:93:5
[13:14:56] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

Below are the details of files I am using in visual studio code

**Conf.ts**

```
import {Config} from 'protractor';

export let config: Config = {

  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome'
  },
  specs: [ '../spec.ts' ],
   onPrepare: () => {
     let globals = require('protractor');
   let browser = globals.browser;
   browser.manage().window().maximize();
   browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
    // doing a browser.get will lead to a transpile error. 
    // undefined does not have a get method
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',

  // You could set no globals to true to avoid jQuery '$' and protractor '$'
  // collisions on the global namespace.
  noGlobals: true
};
```

**spec.ts**

```
import {browser, element, by, By, $, $$, ExpectedConditions} from 'protractor';
//import { ElementFinder, browser, by, element } from 'protractor';
import protractor = require('protractor');

describe('protractor with typescript typings', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    browser.get('http://www.angularjs.org');
  });

  it('should greet the named user', async() => {
    setTimeout(function() {
    // Whatever you want to do after the wait
}, 4000);
    element(by.model('yourName')).sendKeys('Julie');
    let greeting = element(by.binding('yourName'));
   // expect(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
   expect<any>(greeting.getText()).toEqual('Hello Julie!');
  });

  it('should list todos', function() {
    let todoList = element.all(by.repeater('todo in todoList.todos'));
    expect<any>(todoList.count()).toEqual(2);
    expect<any>(todoList.get(1).getText()).toEqual('build an angular app');
  });
});
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "example-typescript",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "a typescript example",
  "author": "",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "pretest": "npm run tsc",
    "test": "protractor tmp/conf.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.47",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.0",
    "jasmine": "^2.4.1",
     "protractor": "file:../",
    "typescript": "~2.1.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jasmine": "^2.5.51",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "^2.0.2",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2"
  }
```

Comment: What is the content of your `tsconfig.json` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the comment discussions, i have changed the conf.ts content **from ../spec.ts to spec.js** and worked fine

**conf.ts**

```
import {Config, browser} from 'protractor';
export let config: Config = {

  framework: 'jasmine',
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
            'args': ['disable-infobars']
        }
  },

  specs: [ 'spec.js' ],
   onPrepare: () => {
     let globals = require('protractor');
   let browser = globals.browser;
   browser.ignoreSynchronization = true;
   browser.manage().window().maximize();
   browser.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5000);
  },
  seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
  noGlobals: true
};
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a `tsconfig.json`, create one. To get a basic one, given your configuration, you can do:

```
npm run tsc -- --init
```

Edit the `module` and `target` properties and make sure they are `commonjs` and `es5` respectively. The error you had is due to the fact that ES6 modules are not yet supported by node. Thus node failed when parsing the `import` token.

Here is an example of `tsconfig.json` that should work for you:

```js
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "target": "es5",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": [
            "dom",
            "es2015",
        ]
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Comment: I have tried with "target" : "es5", but getting error
node_modules/blocking-proxy/built/lib/angular_wait_barrier.d.ts(43,43): error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Promise'. 
but with "es6", at least I could able to open the browser, but no tests run

Comment: That's normal, it's probably because your `lib` flag is missing a few things. Typical value would be `["dom", "es2015"]`. If you want to learn more about the possible values go have a look [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript-Handbook/blob/master/pages/Compiler%20Options.md)

Comment: I just updated my answer with an example of tsconfig that solves your unresolved "Promise" error.

Comment: hv tried with es2015, same issue, can you paste your tsconfig.json, I have taken the tsconfig.json from protractor github, they have "target" : "es6", and how do I fix the lib issue?

Comment: Here is my complete tsconfig.json, still getting same issue - import error
`{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
     "lib": ["dom","es2015"],
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "inlineSourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "outDir": "tmp",
     "types": ["jasmine", "node"]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "asyncAwait",
    "plugins.ts"
  ]
}`

Comment: Hmm... I'm confused. With your setup, it should work. Maybe try to remove `tmp` folder? Does any of the JavaScript file in the `tmp` folder contains an import? Given the config you have they shouldn't.

Comment: tmp is the output folder where the conf.ts transpiles into conf.js, so we can run the test, as i hv written `"test": "protractor tmp/conf.js"` under **package.json**, can you share your code sample in any shared drive so I can look at it...

Comment: I'm sorry for the confusion. What I meant by delete your tmp folder was: tsc is creating that folder when compiling your app, but if nothing is being generated in the tmp folder (for some weird reason), then when you run `protactor tmp/conf.js` it would instead complains about a missing conf.js. From what you described it looks like your problem is that protactor isn't using your compiled spec.js file but your spec.ts file. Actually that migh be just that. Try replacing, in Conf.ts the line `../spec.ts` with `./spec.js`.

Comment: Note that I said `./spec.js` because I expect that your `tmp` folder to contains the files generated by typescript as the same level. So `Conf.js` and `spec.js` are in the same folder. If that's not the case, you would need to replace `./` with whatever map to your folder structure.